# Ember "lastObject.value" render string <DS.PromiseObject:ember1285> in template

Tags: ember.js, promise

Ember `{{lastObject.value}}` render string `<DS.PromiseObject:ember1285>` in template instead of real value.
How to get real value?

Comment: You need to at least tell us what `lastObject` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `{{lastObject.value}}` returns a `DS.PromiseObject`, then you should be able to access the "real value" with the `content` property.

```html
{{lastObject.value.content}}
```

As said on the [Ember data API](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseObject.html) :

> When the promise is resolved, then the resulting value will be set to the PromiseObject's `content` property